# Consulta XML nao retorna a valores

Tags: c#, xml

O objetivo era que retornasse os valores do xml mas não esta retornando nada:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                StreamReader strm = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Visita\\Desktop\\test.xml");
                XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(strm);

                var consulta = from p in xd.Descendants("tb")
                               where p.Element("simbolo").Value == "H"
                               select new
                               {
                                   sa = Convert.ToString(p.Element("simbolo")),
                                   nm = Convert.ToString(p.Element("nAtomic"))
                               };

                foreach (var rs in consulta.ToArray())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(rs.nm));
                } 
                  Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Itens>
  <tb>
    <simbolo>G</simbolo>
    <nAtomic>56</nAtomic>
    <valencia>5</valencia>
  </tb>
  <tb>
    <simbolo>Ga</simbolo>
    <nAtomic>565</nAtomic>
    <valencia>55</valencia>
  </tb>

</Itens>
```

Não esta retornando a valor nenhum, qual o erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retire o *where*, pois com o *where* ele vai filtrar apenas os `<simbolo>H</simbolo>`, e não existe nenhum registro com essa *tag*.

```
where p.Element("simbolo").Value == "H"
```

Ficando assim:

```
StreamReader strm = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Visita\\Desktop\\test.xml");
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(strm);

var consulta = from p in xd.Descendants("tb")
    select new
    {
        sa = Convert.ToString(p.Element("simbolo")),
        nm = Convert.ToString(p.Element("nAtomic"))
    };

    foreach (var rs in consulta.ToArray())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(rs.nm));
    } 
Console.Read();
```

Comment: O problema é que dessa forma eu estou recebendo todos os valores e não apenas o do H (no caso colocaria uma variável para escolher qual valor seria) **Edit:** Ahh n tinha H no xml ops hehe

OBG, consegui kk

Comment: @Lucas, se a resposta está certa, favor colocar como resposta correta. Obrigado